# I want to get hostname and path separately from href tag In Python

Tags: html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, www-mechanize

I have python code from where i want to get hostname and path separately. e.g www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask   I want result like this "host name is: www.stackoverflow.com and path is: /questions/ask"

Here is my python code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urlparse
import mechanize
import socket
import errno
import io
from nyt4 import articalText

url = "http://www.nytimes.com/section/health"
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_equiv(False) 
htmltext = br.open(url)
#htmltext = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
maindiv = soup.findAll('section', attrs={'class':'health-collection collection'})
for links in  maindiv:
    atags = soup.findAll('a',href=True)
    for link in atags:
        alinks= link.get('href')
        print alinks.hostname
        print alinks.path
```

But this code give me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    execfile("nytimes/test2.py")
  File "nytimes/test2.py", line 21, in <module>
    print alinks.hostname
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'hostname'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alinks= link.get('href')` which set alinks to a string whih definitely does not have a hostname or path attribute, you can use [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse) to get the *path* and *hostname*:

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urlparse import urlparse

url = "http://www.nytimes.com/section/health"
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_equiv(False)
htmltext = br.open(url)
#htmltext = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
maindiv = soup.find_all('section', attrs={'class':'health-collection collection'})
for links in  maindiv:
    atags = soup.find_all('a',href=True)
    for link in atags:
        alinks = urlparse(link.get('href'))
        print alinks.hostname
        print alinks.path
```